# python pymongo find KeyError

Tags: python, pymongo

This is the code:

```
select_sql = 'select url from baidu_v_tbl'
results = cur_oracle.execute(select_sql)
`enter code here`urls = results.fetchall()

  logging.info('start........... ')

  for con in urls:
      url = con[0]
      url_v = ''.join(['https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=', url, '@v'])     mongo_records = db_mongo.keywords.find({'url': url_v},{'url': 1, 'keyword': 1}, no_cursor_timeout=True)

     mongo_keywords = [key['keyword'] for key in mongo_records if key['keyword']]
```

This is the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "from_keywords_into_oracle.py", line 44, in <module>
>   mongo_keywords = [key['keyword'] for key in mongo_records]
> KeyError: 'keyword'
> ```

Comment: Can you reindent/reformat your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is clear: "KeyError 'keyword'".

The variable `mongo_records` is a collection of `dict` object (or dict-like) and you get at least an item which doesn't have the key 'keyword'.

You can replace by:

```
mongo_keywords = [key['keyword'] for key in mongo_records if 'keyword' in key]
```

Comment: but now a new question

Comment: @blackang Post a new question on SO, please.

Comment: param = {'keyword': mongo_keywords, 'baidu_ad': u'广告', 'url': url}
update_sql = 'update baidu_v_tbl set keyword = :mongo_keywords, 
                       baidu_ad = :baidu_ad where url = :url'
cur_oracle.execute(update_sql, param)             
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: 非法的变量名/编号